Protobuf parse message fields one at a time
I am familiar with the protobuf wire format where the designers chose not to include the size of the serialized message on the wire.
I am also familiar with the strategies to deal with it from scratch:

mainly delimiting it yourself and manually using the io streams to first fetch the size of a message before parsing it
using the new-ish google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h  which deals with it for you

However, I have a slightly different take (and question).
Given an already serialized message I do not cotrol, I want to load each of its fields one at a time. Note that while the size of the serialized message is not encoded (see previous bullets), the size of each of its fields is encoded. Additionally, the field id is also encoded. See here.
So it should be possible, in theory, to have something like the function ParseMsgField below. Where given a Root object that was previously serialized (and hence, it's fields DID get encoded), load each of its fields one at a time.
package my_proto;

message SubType0 {
    uint32 Val = 1;
}

message SubType1 {
    uint32 Val = 1;
}

message Root {
    repeated SubType0 subtype = 1;
    repeated SubType1 subtype = 2;
}

#include "my_proto.pb.h"

// how to implement this...?
int ParseMsgField(
    google::protobuf::Descriptor* root_descriptor,
    google::protobuf::Message* field_msg,
    google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream& fin
);

int main() {

    int fd = open("my_file", O_RDONLY);
    google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream fin(fd);

    auto* root_descriptor = my_proto::Root::descriptor();

    google::protobuf::Message* field_msg;
    while(true) {
        int field_id = ParseMsgField(root_descriptor, field_msg, fin);
        if (field_id == -1) {
            break;
        }

        // handle each field type, either dynamic_cast or test field_id + static_cast
    }

I'm wondering how to implement the ParseMsgField function? The input parameters I used are guess at what I might need...
I suppose if this was possible, a limitation would be that all subtypes of Root must be message-types for this to work?

While this is just a whole lot of work -- you'll have to do the parsing yourself, instead of just using existing "parse message" functions -- I doubt it will work: since fields can be optional, you wouldn't know whether data that follows is an optional field of your message, or something from the next message.

I'm not sure I understand. As shown, ParseMsgField doesn't take any kind of byte stream. What is it supposed to parse, exactly? Where is that "Root object that was previously serialized" that is supposed to be "given"?

@ChristianStieber you're right.. I was hoping that in terms of the amount of work, it would be a little more work than the parse message functions but not much harder than the parse-delimited versions

@IgorTandetnik oops, yeah I didnt show where the source stream comes from. You can assume its some stream, say from disk that contains the previously serialized Root object

If you just want to read the field tag, use CodedInputStream.ReadTag. Basically, you are looking at re-implementing the whole protobuf parsing code.
